# ABL Progress 4gl : For Each with Count in Output-Stream

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, openedge, progress-4gl

`Progress-Procedure-Editor`:

```
DEFINE STREAM myStream.

OUTPUT STREAM myStream TO 'C:\Temp\BelegAusgangSchnittstelle.txt'.

FOR EACH E_BelegAusgang
    WHERE E_BelegAusgang.Firma = '000'
    AND   E_BelegAusgang.Schnittstelle = '$Standard'
    NO-LOCK:

    PUT STREAM myStream UNFORMATTED
        STRING(E_BelegAusgang.Firma)
        '|'
        STRING(E_BelegAusgang.BelegNummer)
        '|'
        STRING(E_BelegAusgang.Schnittstelle)
        '|'
        SKIP
        .
END.
```

I get this (extraction):

### Firma | BelegNr | Schnittstelle

### 000   | 3   |  $Standard

### 000   | 3   |  $Standard

### 000   | 3   |  $Standard

### 000   | 3   |  $Standard

### 000   | 3   |  $Standard

### 000   | 8   |  $Standard

### 000   | 8   |  $Standard

What I need is to `COUNT` the BelegNr. So I import the data of the `TXT` to `SQL Server`.

On `Server` my query is:

```
SELECT  [BelegNr]
       ,COUNT(*) AS [Anzahl]
FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[Beleg_Ausgang]
GROUP BY [BelegNr]
ORDER BY [Anzahl]
```

With that query I got (extraction):

### BelegNr Anzahl

### 3      |    5

8      |    2

Is there a way to put the `COUNT` directly into the Progress-Code? I mean, I want my result directly from the `Progress-Procedure-Editor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ABL you use `BREAK BY` instead of `GROUP BY`. One limit is that `BREAK BY` groups AND sorts.

You could for instance have another "FOR EACH" for this:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE iCount AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.

FOR EACH E_BelegAusgang NO-LOCK 
    WHERE E_BelegAusgang.Firma = '000'
    AND   E_BelegAusgang.Schnittstelle = '$Standard'
    BREAK BY BelegNr:

    iCount = iCount + 1.

    IF LAST-OF(BelegNr) THEN DO:
        DISPLAY BelegNr iCount.
        iCount = 0.
    END.

END.
```

You could also incorporate that code in the export but note: that will change the order of the file rows. Maybe that's a problem for you, maybe not!